# A random sample of size $25$ is taken from a $N(m, \sigma^2)$. What is the probability that the sample mean will lie between $25$ and $35?$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> **A random sample of size $25$ is taken from a $N(m, \sigma^2)$ with $m=30$ and $\sigma=4$. What is the probability that the sample mean will lie between $25$ and $35?$**

Attempt

$P(25<\bar{x}<35)=P\big(\frac{25-30}{4/5}<z<\frac{35-30}{4/5}\big)=\Phi(6.25)-\Phi(-6.25)=??$
where $\Phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ze^{-x^2/2}dt$

$z=\frac{\bar{x}-m}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ which is the Std Normal dist

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: The sample mean is a linear combination of independent normal random variables; therefore it is normal as well. Try to compute the mean and the variance of the sample mean.

Comment: @Ron Please help me in full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct.
Ordinarily, for such a problem, you might use printed tables of the standard normal distribution $\Phi$, but you will not find the numbers $\pm 6.25$ in
in the margins of such a table, because they are so far from $0$.

The values of $\Phi(-6.25)$ and $\Phi(6.25)$ are very nearly $0$ and $1,$
respectively, so $P(25 \le \bar X \le 35) \approx 1,$ to about 8 decimal places.

Specifically, in R statistical software `pnorm` (without additional
parameters) is the standard normal CDF $\Phi.$

```
pnorm(-6.25)
## 2.052263e-10
pnorm(6.25)
## 1            #correct to 8 decimal places
pnorm(6.25)-1
## -2.052264e-10
```

Almost all (99.7%) of the area under the standard normal density curve
lies between $\pm 3,$ as illustrated in the figure below

[image]